# Javascript Dependency Injection : How to mock dependencies of private variables/functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

What is the idiomatic way to provide dependency injection for the following piece of javascript/nodejs ?  I want to be able to replace util, cfg and call_hard with my own mocks in order to facilitate unit testing :

```
/* file: platform.js */
var config = require('./config'),
    ConfigParser = require('./ConfigParser'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('./util');


function add(dir){
   var xml = util.getConfigFile(dir);
   var cfg = new ConfigParser(xml);
   return call_hard(xml, cfg);
}

function call_hard(xml, cfg){
   ...
}

module.exports.add = add;

/* end of file: platform.js */
```

1- What is the best way to write unit tests for this code ? I want to be able to replace util, cfg and call_hard with my mocks.

I've been added the following code to my platform.js file. It allows me to provide my mocks (it doesn't feel idiomatic to me) :

```
/* file: platform.js */
...
module.exports.set_util = function(new_util) {
   util = new_util;
};
module.exports.set_cfg= function(new_cfg) {
   cfg = new_cfg;
};
module.exports.set_call_hard= function(new_call_hard) {
   call_hard= new_call_hard;
};

/* end of file: platform.js */
```

2- Or should I just write integration tests and not bother ?

3- Any other suggestions on how to write better code / unit tests in JavaScript ?

4- Should I use any other libraries or tools or perspective ? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried jasmine spies? You could spyon(obj.method).andReturn(dummy)

Comment: Hi @sruti, No jasmine spies won't help in this case as we're dealing with private vars/objects/functions.